# CSS - responsivly center div, position fixed

Tags: css

I have a jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/ajvvjnq3/

Really simple, I have a div with fixed width, position fixed and centered.

Below 600px I want the div to be 100% width with 20px margin left and right.

I can't get `margin-right: 20px;`

```css
.block{
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    width: 400px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .block{
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't get `margin-right: 20px;`"?

Comment: the margin-right: 20px; doesn't work, it's flush up against the right side

Comment: @ttmt: try the code I answered below, it will hopefully resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JSfiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/ajvvjnq3/2/

You could try using calc

`width: calc(100% - 40px);` seems to work fine

All its doing here is just negating the values from your margins.

**Edit**
Alternative would be to use @CBroe answer as it supports more browsers than `calc`, but whatever floats your boat:)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .block{
        left: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        width: auto;
        margin: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: [A few browsers will be left behind](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). Mostly Android

Answer (score 3):

I’d simply used this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .block{
        left: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        width: auto;
        margin: auto;
    }
}
```

Positioning the element `20px` from `left` and `right`, and setting `width` to `auto` will make it get the right width while respecting the “gap” you want it to have on either side. And `margin: auto` (`0` would work as well) simply undoes the margin you used earlier to center the element.

https://jsfiddle.net/ajvvjnq3/4/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, it will work..**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .block{
    left: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    position: relative !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t think they want relative positioning (original fiddle still had fixed set explicitly). And what’s with the `!important` on every single property? That’s just not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this replace `width:100%;` with `width:initial;`  add `right:0;`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .block{
        position: fixed;
        top: 50px;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
         right:0;
        width:initial;


    }
}
```

**[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ajvvjnq3/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

calc() makes it easy to position an object with a set margin. In this example, the CSS creates a banner that stretches across the window, with a 20-pixel gap between both sides of the banner and the edges of the window

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/DhwaniSanghvi/okvoLuu5/

```
<div class="block"></div>



.block{
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    width: 400px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .block{
        position: fixed;
        top: 50px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right:20px; 
        left:0;
        width: calc(100% - 40px);
    }
}
```